# CRUD using AJAX & Laravel. After adding a new record, new response (updated data) is not replacing my current tbody of my table WITHOUT RELOADING

Tags: ajax, laravel, crud

1. Data in Table is coming from database

HTML Table Code:

```
<table id="mytable" class="table">
     <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>DB-ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Degree</th>
              <th>Cell</th>
              <th>Edit</th>
              <th>Delete</th>
           </tr>
      </thead>
       <tbody>
            @if ($records->count() > 0)
                @foreach($records as $record)
                      <tr>
                           <td>{{$record->id}}</td>
                           <td>{{$record->name}}</td>
                           <td>{{$record->age}}</td>
                           <td>{{$record->degree}}</td>
                           <td>{{$record->cell}}</td>
                      </tr>
                 @endforeach
            @else
                <span style="color:red">{{ 'Record Not Found' }}</span><br><br>
            @endif
      </tbody>
</table>
```

1. On click `ajax` receives data and stores in database but
2. it is not updating my current `tbody` of table with new response(updated data from database) WITHOUT RELOADING
3. using `$("tbody").html(responce);` it vanishes all table record
4. using `$("tbody").append(responce)`; no change occur
5. using `$("tbody").html(row);` all previous record vanishes and only new row is shown
6. using `$("tbody").append(row);` it do not vanish previous record and show all rows as well
7. I want to update my current table with new data WITHOUT RELOADING

AJAX Code:

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: " {{route('record.create')}}",
            data: {name: name, age: age, degree: degree, cell: cell},
            success: function (responce) {
                // location.reload(); 
                    $.each(responce, function( index, value ) {
                    var row = $("<tr><td>" 
                                + value.id + "</td><td>" 
                                + value.name + "</td><td>" 
                                + value.age + "</td><td>" 
                                + value.degree + "</td><td>" 
                                + value.cell + "</td></tr>");

                  // $("tbody").html(responce); //all table record vanished
                  // $("tbody").append(responce); //no change
                  // $("tbody").html(row);  //all previous record vanish and new row shown
                  // $("tbody").append(row); //not vanish previous record and show all rows as well 
                });
            }
        });
```

web.php Route:

```
Route::get('main', 'CrudController@store')->name('record.create');
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $record = new Record($request->except('_token'));
    $record->save();

    $records = Record::all(); 

    return Response::json($records);

}
```

View All Record route:

```
Route::get('record', 'CrudController@view')->name('record.view');
```

view Controller:

```
public function view()
{
    $records = Record::all(); 

    return view('main', compact('records'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should vanish your table first before inject new data from response.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: " {{route('record.create')}}",
        data: {name: name, age: age, degree: degree, cell: cell},
        success: function (responce) {
             $('#formdata')[0].reset();
             $("tbody").html("");
             $.each(responce, function( index, value ) {
                var row = $("<tr><td>" 
                            + value.id + "</td><td>" 
                            + value.name + "</td><td>" 
                            + value.age + "</td><td>" 
                            + value.degree + "</td><td>" 
                            + value.cell + "</td></tr>");

                $("tbody").append(row);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: WOW great. it works . but the input fields of my form don't refresh and it contains old values in the fields. how to empty my input fields without reloading

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check how I reset the form

Comment: oh it don't works: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined @saengdaet

Comment: what is the `id` of the form?

Comment: <form id="formdata" method="">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203640/discussion-between-saengdaet-and-imran).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tbody").html("");
                jQuery.each(data, function(key,value){
                 // $('#org_name').text( value.name );
                  $("table").append("<tr><td>" 
                            + value.id + "</td><td>" 
                            + value.name + "</td><td>" 
                            + value.age + "</td><td>" 
                            + value.degree + "</td><td>" 
                            + value.cell + "</td></tr>");
});
```

**it append tbody multiple time change "tbody" to "table" and boom it will start working fine**

Comment: The code you posted is *not* a runnable snippet (just click the "Run..." button and you will realize that)! Please edit your answer and format your code as a **plain code block** instead (use simple, three back-tick code fences).